# split a pandas column in to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the area of the image as follows:

```
labeled_mask, num_labels = ndimage.label(mask, structure=s)
clusters = measure.regionprops(labeled_mask, image) 
propList = ['Area',
        'MajorAxisLength',
        'MinorAxisLength',
        'Centroid']
          
output_file = open('draft_Stelle_measurements.csv', 'w')
output_file.write(',' + ",".join(propList) + '\n')

for cluster_props in clusters:
    #output cluster properties to the excel file
    output_file.write(str(cluster_props['Label']))
    for i,prop in enumerate(propList):
        if(prop == 'Area'): 
            to_print = cluster_props[prop]   #Convert pixel square to um square
        elif(prop == 'orientation'): 
            to_print = cluster_props[prop]*57.2958  #Convert to degrees from radians
        elif(prop.find('Intensity') < 0):          # Any prop without Intensity in its name
            to_print = cluster_props[prop]#*pixels_to_um
        else: 
            to_print = cluster_props[prop]     #Reamining props, basically the ones with Intensity in its name
       output_file.write(',' + str(to_print))
output_file.write('\n')
```

output_file.close()   #Closes the file, otherwise it would be read only.

Here is the value of the `Centroid` stored in `MinorMajorAxisLength` where this parameter has its own value.

How to fix this? then I want to do the following task:

I want to split it into `Centroid_x` and `Centroid_y`. When I want to check the `df.head()` It shows like this:

[image]

when I run `df.columns`:

`Index(['Index', 'Area', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength', 'Centroid', 'area_in_nm2', 'radius_in_nm'],dtype='object')`

but when I want to check the `df['Centorid]`, this only print the second value like:

`595.7452511811783)`

`1419.272292040694)`

`1805.6373032652102)`

I want to remove the `(` and `)` from this column and then split them into `Centroid_x` and `Centroid_y`. Here is what I did:

```
df[['Centrod_x','Centroid_y']] = df.Centroid.str.split(")",expand=True)
```

Comment: Where is the `_` in `595.7452511811783)` ?

Comment: Also it looks like your `Centroid_x` might be in the `MinorAxisLength` column

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is some data issue here, with the *Centroid_x* and *MinorAxisLength* columns

Comment: column titles are right aligned to the content. there is only one value under Centroid that ends with close parenthesis. While MinorAxisLength values starts with open parenthesis

Comment: @Zia, could you also share the first 2-5 lines of the file (`csv` maybe?) you are using to create the dataframe? There is probably some problem with the commas inside as other commenters mentioned.

Comment: yes, the value of the first parenthesis is switched to `MinorAxisLength`.  @Naveed, sure I will share the rest of the code.

Comment: @yeti, Can you check the whole code now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `measure.regionprops` method, I used the `measure.regionprops_table` and produce the data in the correct format.

```
props = measure.regionprops_table(labeled_mask, image, properties=('area',
                                                                'axis_major_length',
                                                               'axis_minor_length',
                                                                  'centroid',))
df = pd.DataFrame(props)
df.head(5)
```

[image]